# slope comparisons given by independant measurements

Tags: r, covariance, variance

With the data used in a previous question
[matplot/ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977249/ggplot-equivalent-for-matplot/30977801?noredirect=1#comment49998870_30977801)

```
data<-rbind(c(6,16,25), c(1,4,7), c(NA, 1,2), c(NA, NA, 1))
as.data.frame(data)
matplot(data, log="y",type='b', pch=1)
```

giving this plot (here treated only wih matplot)
[image]

These data represent data for Species A (y=log(nb of branches), x = maximum order of the object, 2 , 3 or 4). I twant now to compare statistically the 3 slopes ; knowing that the 3 lines are independant (on differents objects).
I also would like to compare these slopes between two species A and B (image of B not given).

On my real data, I made a bartlet test, and I founded homoscedasticity.

**Is an Ancova the good way to compare these slopes?**

Thanks !

Comment: This question is primarily statistical, not about programming, so it is being migrated to our sister site, Stats.StackExchange.com.